# Force the file opened with "r+" to end

Tags: ruby, file

There is a file with some marker word in it:

```
qwerty
I am the marker!
zxcvbn
123456
```

I want to overwrite all the rest of the file after the marker with some unknown amount of lines instead:

```
qwerty
I am the marker!
inserted line #1
inserted line #2
inserted line #3
```

But if there are too few lines to be inserted, the tail can be still there, that I do not need:

```
qwerty
I am the marker!
inserted line #1
123456
```

Here is my code (simplified):

```
File.open("file.txt", "r+") do |file|

  file.gets "marker"
  file.gets

  lines_to_insert.each do |line|
    file.puts line
  end

  # I wish I could do file.put_EOF here

end
```

Comment: Reading a file, `gsub` on it’s content and writing it back is not an option?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-truncate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File.open("file.txt", "r+") do |file|

  file.gets "marker"
  file.gets

  lines_to_insert.each do |line|
    file.puts line
  end

  # EOF here
  file.truncate(file.pos)

end
```

Making use of `File#pos` to specify where to truncate.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a temp file?

```
File.open("file.tmp", "w") do |tmp_file|
  File.open("file.txt", "r+") do |file|

    file.readlines.each do |line|
      # add each line of the original file up to and including marker line
      tmp_file.puts line
      if line.include? "marker" #or however you're indicating marker
        break
      end
    end

    # add new lines
    lines_to_insert.each do |line|
      tmp_file.puts line
    end
  end
end
FileUtils.mv 'file.tmp', 'file.txt'
```

This will guarantee a file with a proper EOF line and not a hacky set of lines at the end that are nothing but newline characters or spaces.

Answer (score -1):

Why not fill an array with each line, by using something like this:

`array = file.split("\\\n")`

Then you can just find the index of the array that contains the word marker

`marker_index = array.index{|line|line.include('marker')}`

Then just add random values to any `index > marker_index`

Finally concatenate all the strings in your array (don't forget to add your \n back in) and write back to your file.